# sorting with Map<String, Integer> from highest to lowest

Tags: java

I am a bit stuck on how to sort the frequency of a word from any text file input.  I was able to code the frequency of each code but I'm not sure how to sort them out from the most frequently occurring word.

This is what I have for the frequency.

For example. I have a file text that read.

```
This is a test run. 
I come with no wrapping or pretty pink bows. 
I am who I am from my head to my toes. 
I tend to get loud when speaking my mind. 
Even a little crazy some of the time.
I. am. who. I. am.
```

the output with this code is.

```
2   a
2   am
2   am.
1   bows.
1   come
1   crazy
1   even
1   from
1   get
1   head
4   i
2   i.
1   is
1   little
1   loud
1   mind.
3   my
1   no
1   of
1   or
1   pink
1   pretty
1   run.
1   some
1   speaking
1   tend
1   test
1   the
1   this
1   time.
2   to
1   toes.
1   when
1   who
1   who.
1   with
1   wrapping
```

I was also wondering how can I ignore the period because some same words are being overcounted because of the period.

```
   Scanner input;
            try {
                input = new Scanner(file);
                 Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
                    while (input.hasNext()) {
                        String next = input.next().toLowerCase();
                        if (!wordCounts.containsKey(next)) {
                            wordCounts.put(next, 1);
                        } else {
                            wordCounts.put(next, wordCounts.get(next) + 1);
                        }
                    }

                    //  report frequencies

                    for (String word : wordCounts.keySet()) {
                        int count = wordCounts.get(word);

                            System.out.println(count + "\t" + word);
                    }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: You first question has an answer here: [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java). As for your second question, try using 'substring()'.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that post!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the "." you can do the following:

```
final String cleaned = next.replace(".", "");
```